# alert if any of radio buttons out of different sets of radio button is left out before button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I have this jquery which takes radio button inputs from different sets of radio buttons. I want alert the user if any of these 3 or none are checked before button click.
Here is the jquery:

```
 $("#query").click(function() {  

  $("#loading-div-background").show();
  $("#img").hide()
  $("#container").hide();

  var category = $('input:radio[name=category]:checked').val();
  var time = $('input:radio[name=time]:checked').val()
  var plotchoice = $('input:radio[name=plotchoice]:checked').val()
  var qu = {"category":category,"time":time,"plotchoice":plotchoice}
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async:true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "/query",
    data: JSON.stringify(qu),
    success: function (data) {     
     var graph = $("#container");
     graph.html(data);   
     $("#loading-div-background").hide();      
     $("#container").show();
   },
   dataType: "html"
 });
});
```

here is the html:

```
 <label style="font-family: Comic Sans MS;">Choose a category:</label><br/>

    <!--set 1-->

<input type="radio" name="category" value="c1"><label style="margin-left: 10px;font-family: Comic Sans MS;; vertical-align: middle;">Status</label> </input>
&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="category" value="c2"><label style="margin-left: 10px;font-family: Comic Sans MS;; vertical-align: middle;">Trend</label> </input><br>
<!-- sset 2-->
<br/>

<label style="font-family: Comic Sans MS;">Choose a time frame:</label><br/>
<input type="radio" name="time" value="t1"><label style="margin-left: 10px;font-family: Comic Sans MS;; vertical-align: middle;"> Recently</label> </input>
&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="time" value="t2"><label style="margin-left: 10px;font-family: Comic Sans MS;; vertical-align: middle;"> Last 1 Week</label> </input>
&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="time" value="t2"><label style="margin-left: 10px;font-family: Comic Sans MS;; vertical-align: middle;"> Last 1 Month</label> </input>
&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="time" value="t2"><label style="margin-left: 10px;font-family: Comic Sans MS;; vertical-align: middle;"> Last 1 Year </label></input>
&nbsp;
<br/>
<br/>
<!--set 3-->

<label style="margin-left: 10px;font-family: Comic Sans MS;">Choose a plot type:</label><br/>
<input type="radio" name="plotchoice" value="p1"><label style="margin-left: 10px;font-family: Comic Sans MS;;  vertical-align: middle;"> Bar </label></input>
&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="plotchoice" value="p2"><label style="margin-left: 10px;font-family: Comic Sans MS;;  vertical-align: middle;"> Line </label></input><br>
<br/>
<button type="button" id="query" style="font-family: Comic Sans MS;;  vertical-align: middle;">View Plot</button>
```

As you can see i've labelled the 3 sets of radio button from which one froo each set needs to be selected before button click. If any of it is left out or if none are selected, i want to display warning.
 note:New to jquery

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Can check the state of radio buttons like this:

```
$('button').click(function() {
  if ($('#radio').is(':checked')) { 
    console.log("Is checked"); 
  } else {
    console.log("Not checked");
  }
});
```